# add a alt text on image in react quilljs text editor

Tags: next.js, text-editor, react-quilljs

I use recat quilljs text editor and when I had uploading image i had also set a alt text on image
I coding next.js app website and thank u

I expect a code next.js for upload image to react quilljs text editor with alt text on image